# If $A$ and $B$ each have at least two elements, then not every element of $P(A × B)$ has the form $ A_1 \times B_1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The full definition is:

If $A$ and $B$ each have at least two elements, then not every element of
$P(A \times B)$ has the form $A_1 \times B_1$ for some $A_1 \in P(A)$ and $B_1 \in P(B)$.

Well In my opinion it is not difficult to understand why this is true, If I have for example $A=\{A_1,A_2\}$ and $B=\{B_1,B_2\}$ then I will have an element in $A\times B$ that is $A_1\times B_2$ that would result in $(A_1,B_2)$ and then $\{(A_1,B_2)\}\in P(A\times B)$.

But this definition is so obvious I am having trouble writing up a formal proof. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be distinct elements of $A$ and let $b_1$ and $b_2$ be distinct elements of $B$. Then $C := \{(a_1,b_1), (a_2,b_1), (a_1,b_2)\} \in P(A \times B)$. To see that it is not of the form $A_1 \times B_1$, note that if that were the case, then:

1. $A_1$ must contain both $a_1$ and $a_2$ (else we miss either $(a_1,b_1)$ or $(a_2,b_1)$ from the product).
2. $B_1$ must contain both $b_1$ and $b_2$ (else we miss either $(a_1,b_1)$ or $(a_1,b_2)$ from the product).
3. Thus, $A_1 \times B_1$ must contain $(a_2, b_2)$, which $C$ does not.

Thus, $C$ cannot be such a product, and we win.

Comment: Awesome! I understand everything up to step 3, because I thought that $C$  does contain $(a_2, b_2)$ because wouldnt that be the cartesian product of $a_2\times b_2$?

Comment: That's the point: $A_1 \times B_1$ contains $(a_2, b_2)$, but $C$ doesn't: $C$ contains only the three elements that I defined it to contain.

Comment: What is the logic in defining the set with only 3 elements and not including all of them, doesnt having $(a_1,b2)$ or $(a_2, b1)$ already show that not every element is of that form?

Comment: You can do the same thing with $C$ including only those two elements, sure. I wrote it with three out of habit, more than anything. But you can't include all of them: that wouldn't help, because if you did, we'd have $C = \{a_1, a_2\} \times \{b_1, b_2\}$.

Comment: I see, so the goal of this is to show if we take some subset of $A\times B$ which is an element of $P(A\times B)$  then not every element in said subset will be of that form? Correct?

Comment: No: we want to show that the set that we've taken is not of the desired form.